# Subquery returns more than one row error when one row is returned

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently doing some SQL magic and wanted to update the stock in my companies ERP program. However if I try to run the following query I get the error mentioned in the title.

```
update llx_product lp
set stock = (select sum(ps.reel)
             from llx_product_stock as ps, llx_entrepot as w 
             where w.entity IN (1) 
               and w.rowid = ps.fk_entrepot 
               and ps.fk_product = lp.rowid
             group by ps.rowid)
```

The subquery by itself returns just one row if used with a rowid for the product.

```
select sum(ps.reel)
from llx_product_stock as ps, llx_entrepot as w
where w.entity in (1) 
  and w.rowid = ps.fk_entrepot 
  and ps.fk_product = 7372
group by ps.rowid
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.

Comment: It would be better if you share the table structure and sample data. [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing the query as:

```
update llx_product lp
    set stock = (select sum(ps.reel)
                 from llx_product_stock ps join
                      llx_entrepot w 
                      on ps.fk_product = lp.rowid
                 where w.entity in (1) and
                       w.rowid = ps.fk_entrepot
                );
```

An aggregation query with no `group by` cannot return more than one row.  It is unclear how your version is returning more than one row because the key used in the `group by` also has an equality comparison.  Perhaps there is some type conversion issue at play.

But in any case, without the `group by`, you cannot get the error you are currently getting.

Comment: Thanks Gordon that was almost it, totally missed that you cannot use the outer table in the subquery. I found a very easy solution, it seems I tried to do this the hard way ^^

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering the solution to my issue was a very simple query, Gordon pointed in the right direction and I made it harder than it should be.

```
update llx_product lp
left join llx_product_stock ps on lp.rowid = ps.fk_product
set lp.stock = ps.reel
```